# JAVA JSCH does not understan record format from known_host file

Tags: java, jsch, unknown-host

I don't know how this works so I came here for help.

I use JSCH java library to ssh from one machine to another. My program fails indicating unknown host error. However the entry is in the known_host file.

I noticed that JSCH does not understand records from known_host file of this format:

> |1|asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdsaf=|asdfasdfasdfadfas=ssh-rsa
>   asdfasdfasdfasdfasd

but understands this format (I added it manually and it worked):

> host ssh-rsa asgfsdfadfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfa

How to make in understand the first format? My config on Session is the following:

> ```
>       this.sesConnection.setConfig("HashKnownHosts", "yes");
>       this.sesConnection.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
> ```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you expect it to understand the first format?

Comment: Because SSH client from the machine uses this format and I want to be consistent.

Comment: What SSH client? I've never seen this format. And digging into OpenSSH code, it does not even look like it ever uses this format.

Comment: host ssh-rsa asgfsdfadfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfa This format I got from JSCH and ssh client OpenSSH does understand it!